# How do I escape quotes in nested Ruby within SQLite?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm trying to pull data from a Menu table in my database. 
Let's say x is the name of a restaurant:

```
x = Applebee's
```

In my controller, I'm trying to pull specific food items that meet user-selected criteria (so in this example, the selected calories are 750, the selected category is chicken, so those are passed into the params):

```
@items = Menu.where("calories <= '#{params[:calories]}' AND category = '#{params[:category]}' AND restaurant = \'#{x}\'")
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

> `SQLite3::SQLException: near "s": syntax error: SELECT "menus".* FROM
>   "menus"  WHERE (calories <= '750' AND category = 'Chicken' AND
>   restaurant = 'Applebee's')`

It works fine when the restaurant has a name without an apostrophe. Any ideas as to how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@items = Menu.scoped
@items = @items.where("calories <= (?)", params[:calories])
@items = @items.where(:category => params[:category])
@items = @items.where(:restaurant => x)
```

or

```
@items = Menu.where(
           "calories <= (?)", params[:calories]
         ).where(
           :category => params[:category]
         ).where(
           :restaurant => x
         )
```

Comment: This worked for me, the second solution you provided, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something more like

```
@items = Menu.where(
    "calories <= :calories AND category = :category AND restaurant = :restaurant", 
    {calories: params[:calories], category: params[:category], restaurant: x}
)
```